# How does 'super' works with multi-inheritance with arguments in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiple-inheritance, super

I have the following code:

```
class TestA(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(TestA, self).__init__()
        print 'TestA'

class TestB(object):
    def __init__(self, my_var=None):
        super(TestB, self).__init__()
        print 'TestB', my_var

class TestC(object):
    def __init__(self, my_var=None):
        super(TestC, self).__init__()
        print 'TestC', my_var

class TestD(TestB, TestA, TestC):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'TestD'
        super(TestD, self).__init__("Hello World")

TestD() # Start from here
```

And the output is

```
TestD
TestC None
TestA None
TestB Hello World
```

I would expect to have :

```
TestD
TestB Hello World
TestA Hello World
TestC Hello World
```

What's wrong in my code or my understanding?

If I remove **super** on **TestA**, **TestB**, **TestC** and I call 3 times **super** like below, I have the expected output. (But I don't want to call three times super)

```
class TestD(TestB, TestA, TestC):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'TestD'
        super(TestD, self).__init__("Hello World")
        super(TestD, self).__init__("Hello World")
        super(TestD, self).__init__("Hello World")
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your methods aren't forwarding any arguments when they use `super`.

Comment: Now look here, `super` is nothing special. It lets you access your parent class's attributes. That's it. That's all it does. It doesn't magically call _all_ parent classes' constructors (which is how you wrote your code in your previous question), nor does it magically insert arguments into your `__init__()` call with no arguments.

Comment: Super looks to call the TestA, TestB, TestC __init__ functions, but only TestB receives the parameter "Hello World". I do not see magic with this, but it inserts arguments into my __init__(). Otherwise I could not print it.

Comment: No, it doesn't do that for you. _You_ are passing an argument here: `super(TestD, self).__init__("Hello World")`. That's why TestB receives an argument. But then in TestB you do this: `super(TestB, self).__init__()` and that's why TestA doesn't get any arguments.

Comment: If you have more questions about `super`, I suggest you join us in [the python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python). It's easier to answer questions like yours there. And it's better than getting posting more questions and getting them closed as duplicates.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, I will ask there. I understand better how it works but i don't see a way to solve my issue.